# How to use python project as package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I copied project( /cyphers) into my project (./), so i want to somehow do
./cyphers/main.py

```
from kyber import Kyber768
pk, sk =Kyber768.keygen()
c, key =Kyber768.enc(pk)
_key = Kyber768.dec(c,sk)
print(key)
print(_key)
```

but outside ./cyphers, in my project directory(./), for that reason i created
./main2.py

```
from cyphers.kyber import Kyber768
pk, sk =Kyber768.keygen()
c, key =Kyber768.enc(pk)
_key = Kyber768.dec(c,sk)
print(key)
print(_key)
```

That give me the next error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khamitov02/laba/dabudimesh/dabudimesh/main2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cyphers.kyber import Kyber768
  File "/home/khamitov02/laba/dabudimesh/dabudimesh/cyphers/kyber.py", line 3, in <module>
    from polynomials import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polynomials'
```

*polynomials.py is imported in kyber.py
I tried to add `from cyphers.polynomials import *`, but get the same error. That's my project structure

```
khamitov02@DESKTOP-L203LU5:~/laba/dabudimesh/dabudimesh$ tree -L 2
.
├── \
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── config.cpython-310.pyc
│   ├── message.cpython-310.pyc
│   ├── router.cpython-310.pyc
│   ├── shell.cpython-310.pyc
│   └── utils.cpython-310.pyc
├── config.py
├── cyphers
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── aes256_ctr_drbg.py
│   ├── assets
│   ├── baby-kyber.py
│   ├── benchmark_kyber.py
│   ├── kyber.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── modules.py
│   ├── ntt_helper.py
│   ├── polynomials.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── test_kyber.py
│   └── utils.py
├── gg.py
├── main.py
├── main2.py
```

Comment: Ok, i just found an answer myself. I just made from .polynomials import *, not from polynomials import * into kyber.py file. So dot was important thing here